# Multiple Annotations loaded from plist using custom overlays

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I cant seem to figure out why I get this error and have stumped myself:

> An instance 0x7c763e0 of class PlaceMark was deallocated while key
>   value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was
>   leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object.
>   Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.
>   Here's the current observation info: `<NSKeyValueObservationInfo
>   0x7c77220> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x7c77070: Observer: 0x7ba10c0, Key
>   path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: YES> Context:
>   0x0, Property: 0x7c76b00>)`

My Plist example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>caloosahatchee</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Punta Rassa Boat Ramp</string>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <string>26.48444444444444</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <string>-82.010277777777778</string>
        <key>coordinates</key>
        <string>N26 29 04 W81 00 37</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Boat ramp with fish cleaning station and several long docks.\n(239) 533-7275</string>
        <key>icons</key>
        <string>CFILH</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Cape Harbour</string>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <string>26.48015</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <string>-81.96936</string>
        <key>coordinates</key>
        <string>N26 32 38 W82 00 28</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Marina with bait/tackle shop, kayak rentals and access to restaurant and shops. Boat docks and paddle craft landing.\n(239) 945-4330</string>
        <key>icons</key>
        <string>FNLJI</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tarpon Point</string>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <string>26.53922222222222</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <string>-82.00027777777777778</string>
        <key>coordinates</key>
        <string>N26 32 21.2 W82 00 01</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>Full-service marina and resort with special kayak launch (fee), boat/kayak rentals, charters and ship’s store.\n(239) 542-6222</string>
        <key>icons</key>
        <string>FMNLJI</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my viewForAnnotation and CallOutAccessory:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation: (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
if(annotation != mapview.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure] retain];
    pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


} else {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D userLoc;
    userLoc.latitude = mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    userLoc.longitude = mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;

    int degrees = userLoc.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(userLoc.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];

    degrees = userLoc.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(userLoc.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];

    NSString *coordinate_l = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",lat,@", ",longt];

    [mapview.userLocation setSubtitle:coordinate_l];
    [mapview.userLocation setTitle:@"Coordinates:"];
}
return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView pinView:(MKAnnotationView *)pinView calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
dViewController = [[detailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];

PlaceMark *theAnnotation = (PlaceMark *) pinView.annotation;

dViewController.descriptiontext = theAnnotation.description;
dViewController.titletext = theAnnotation.title;
dViewController.icontext = theAnnotation.text;

[self presentModalViewController:dViewController animated:true];
[dViewController release];
}
```

Here is my PlaceMark Class:

```
@interface PlaceMark : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

NSString *currentSubTitle;
NSString *currentTitle;
NSString *currentDescription;
NSString *currentText;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentSubTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentText;

- (NSString *)title;
- (NSString *)subtitle;
- (NSString *)description;
- (NSString *)text;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c;

@end

@implementation PlaceMark
@synthesize coordinate,currentTitle,currentSubTitle,currentDescription,currentText;

- (NSString *)subtitle{
return currentSubTitle;
}
- (NSString *)title{
return currentTitle;
}
- (NSString *)description{
return currentDescription;
}
- (NSString *)text{
return currentText;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
coordinate=c;
NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude);
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
self.currentDescription=nil;
self.currentText=nil;
self.currentSubTitle=nil;
self.currentTitle=nil;

[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Custom load function for Annotations:

```
- (void)loadLeeAnnotations{
//retrieve path of plist file and populate relevant types with its information
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Coordinates" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *rootPlistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableArray *arboAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//NSMutableDictionary *arboDict = [rootPlistDict objectForKey:key];
NSArray *annotationsArray = [rootPlistDict objectForKey:@"lee"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
for(NSDictionary *annotationContainerDict in annotationsArray){

    workingCoordinate.latitude = [[annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude = [[annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
     //NSLog(@"latitude: %f Longitude %f",workingCoordinate.latitude,workingCoordinate.longitude);
    PlaceMark *addAnn = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate] autorelease];
    [addAnn setCurrentTitle:[annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [addAnn setCurrentSubTitle:[annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"coodinates"]];
    [addAnn setCurrentText:[annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"icons"]];
    [addAnn setCurrentDescription: [annotationContainerDict objectForKey:@"description"]];
    [arboAnnotations addObject:addAnn];

}//for
//NSLog(@"The content of array is %@",arboAnnotations);
mapview.delegate = self;
[mapview addAnnotations:arboAnnotations];
[arboAnnotations release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed Thanks Anna! the comment on removing

```
[addAnn release];
```

From the custom annotation loading class seems to have fixed the issue. Now I need to get my annotation popup to show they don't seem to be clickable and do nothing when i click on them.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means the coordinates are invalid.
Latitude must be from -90 to 90 and longitude must be from -180 to 180.

Perhaps the code is using the longitude value for latitude and vice-versa (or maybe the values in the plist are backwards)?

Comment: I dont think that is my problem since one of the overlays is loading properly. I added my plist above in the code.

Comment: By "overlay" do you mean a PlaceMark annotation?  Can you show how you create and add the placemarks to the map?

Comment: I added my custom load annotation functions above which runs when they select which map they want to view from a PickerView didSelectRow

Comment: In the code, you are getting the placemarks for "lee" which I assume is not the same as "caloosahatchee".  When you NSLog the coordinates, are the lat/longs correct?  The one thing that doesn't look right is the line `[addAnn release];`.  You shouldn't do that because you've already called `autorelease` on it in the alloc+init line.  Remove the `[addAnn release];`.

Comment: lee is also in the plist i only cut out 3 of the plist items. Thanks on the release catch

Comment: Unrelated but the first call to `setCurrentText` (for "name") should possibly be `setCurrentTitle` instead.

Comment: Yes, the setCurrentText was unrelated.  I've only seen this "Observation info was leaked" error with the map view when adding an annotation with invalid coordinates.  There are some other questions and answers on SO in relation to this error.  You could try them.